# how to gather user input via keypad on twilio using node js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to specify an action to be taken after user input on the keypad is collected in an outbound call by making use of a different route, but then after twiml says the content of the first route it says the app has crashed and ends the call.

```
app.post('/getCalls', (req, res) => {
const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
const gather = twiml.gather({ 
    numDigits: '1',
    action: '/for-1',
});
gather.say('Hey, this is my small twilio app, press 1 for sales. Press 2 for 
support.');
twiml.redirect('/getCalls');
res.type('text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
});

app.post('/for-1', (req, res) => {
const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
if(req.body.Digits) {
    switch(req.body.Digits){
        case '1':
            twiml.say('You selected sales. Good for you!');
            break;
        case '2':
            twiml.say('You need support. We will help!');
            break;
        default: 
            twiml.say("Sorry, I don't understand that   choice.").pause();
            twiml.redirect('/getCalls');
            break; 
    }
} else{
    twiml.redirect('/getCalls');  
}
res.type('text/xml');
res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Please, any ideas on what i need to do for twiml to say the content of the route when a user selects an option?

Comment: Can you paste the crash error message? the code seems fine tho

Comment: What does the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger) say?